# identifying Outlook Distribution Groups using c#

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

How can I check if the mail recipient is a Distribution group in outlook using c#.Once done,I just have to display a message in a message box.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the [AddressEntryUserType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860674(v=office.15).aspx) property of the AddressEntry class. For example:

```
    Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
        snd.Recipients[1].AddressEntry;
    if (addrEntry.AddressEntryUserType ==
        Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
        olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry)
    {
       // dist list
    }
```

Comment: olOutlookDistributionListAddressEntry is another possible value.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Recipient.AddressEntry.Members is not null.